# Facebook Graph API live_videos endpoint on personal profile pages

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, video

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to access the `live_videos` endpoint for Business Pages (aka fan pages, like pages, etc.) and it's working great.

I need to be able to access the [live_videos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/live_videos/) endpoint on a user personal profile. I've gone through the app verification process and Facebook has granted my app permission to `user_videos` and `user_posts`.

My app also has an App Page assigned to it and I've generated a [never expire token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39182923/1177153) for that app page.

Using the Graph API Explorer with the never-expire access token and I query `/{user-id}/live_videos`, I don't get the live video for that person's profile. I can see the VOD (Video On Demand) videos, but not the live video.

This app is used on my website which embeds the live video from storm chasers. So there is a simple server-side script which would use the access token to check the `{user-id}/live_videos` endpoint, and if `"status": "LIVE"`, I get the embed URL. When they go offline, I stop showing the embed.

My question is, am I using the never-expire access token correctly? 
Or should I be saving each user's access token and querying the `/me/live_videos` endpoint with their individual token? If I do that, then the token expires in 60 days.

My thought was that if Facebook has granted me `user_videos` and `user_posts`, then my app should be able to access that somehow.

**Update**: I've tried saving the user's access token when they login, then I access https://graph.facebook.com/me/live_videos?access_token= with the access token and I get:

```
"error": {
      "message": "(#100) No permission to perform current operation."
}
```

[According to the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/live_videos/), the token should have permissions.